# .mouseleave() activate only when moving out of specific border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a roll up div while mouse is over another div. It opens but I'd like it not to close when leaving through the bottom border. Is it possible using JS or JQuery? Here is my current code:

```
$("#sell1").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#rollup1").css("display","inline");
    });
    $("#rollup1").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#rollup1").css("display","none");
    });
    $("#sell1").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#rollup1").css("display","none");
    });
```

Comment: Post the `html` too

Comment: I am not good in javascript at all but I manage trying alternative solutions like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/z907hyv4/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When processing the `mouseleave`, you can get the dimensions of the element and see whether the event's `pageY` is below the element:

```js
$("#rollup1").mouseenter(function() {
  $("#status").text("Over the element...");
});
$("#rollup1").mouseleave(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var bottom = $this.offset().top + $this.height();
  if (bottom < e.pageY) {
    $("#status").text("Left via bottom edge");
  } else {
    $("#status").text("Left NOT via bottom edge");
  }
});
```

```css
#rollup1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="rollup1"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```